# LaTeX/plain TeX macro: style a box with custom borders and padding

Tags: boxes, line

I'd like to make a LaTeX environment for a styled box without using any additional packages, just defining some lines and spaces. I have already come far, but failing with the last line I imagined in this instance I realize that I don't have the correct impression of the underlying box model yet.

Target: A box with custom border lines, some padding and the possibility of any other LaTeX command inside. In this instance, I imagine a box with a thick line  and a thin line along the left, while the thinner line joins the left tip of a short horizontal segment at the top, while the right side is like a 180° rotated copy of it, just without the thicker line.

In my class file I have already realized this as far as

```
\newenvironment{interrupt} {%
    \vspace{2em}%
    \noindent%
    \hspace{2.5pt}\rule{2em}{.2pt}\hspace{-2em}\hspace{-2.5pt}%
    \vline width .8pt%
    \hspace{1.5pt}%
    \vline width .2pt%
    \hspace{2em}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.9\linewidth}
    \vspace{1em}%
} {%
    \vspace{.5em}%
    \end{minipage}%
    %\vfill
    \hspace{2em}\vline width .2pt%
    \vfill%
    %\hspace{-2em}%
    \hfill%
    \rule{2em}{.2pt}%
    \vspace{2em}%
}
```

But the bottom right segment does not behave as I would expect it to and everything I tried about properly aligning it failed. So where am I thinking wrong?

If there's a good resource which explains this in detail and I just missed it, please link it!

*Bonus question: OT, but related to the example, what is the best way to make the inner box dynamically use all available space minus the required padding?*

***Edit:*** minimal example of my specific case, as requested

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{interrupt} {%
    \vspace{2em}%
    \noindent%
    \hspace{2.5pt}\rule{2em}{.2pt}\hspace{-2em}\hspace{-2.5pt}%
    \vline width .8pt%
    \hspace{1.5pt}%
    \vline width .2pt%
    \hspace{2em}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.9\linewidth}
    \vspace{1em}%
} {%
    \vspace{.5em}%
    \end{minipage}%
    %\vfill
    \hspace{2em}\vline width .2pt%
    %\vfill%
    %\hspace{-2em}%
    %\hfill%
    \rule{2em}{.2pt}%
    \vspace{2em}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

Bla, bla blabla bla, bla.\\
Ba di da bla

\begin{interrupt} % the session and discussion is interrupted
    % and may be continued in the same context later
    How nice, a custom sample text.

    \begin{tabular}{c | c c}
        1   & 2 & 3\\\hline
        4   & 5 & 6\\
        7   & 8 & 9
    \end{tabular}
\end{interrupt}

Back to same bla\dots

\end{document}
```

[image: right horizontal segment should atach to lower end, pointing left]

Comment: Just to understand, with the `\vfill`, you want it to fill up all available space on the page?

Comment: What's your target TeX *format*? LaTeX or plain TeX? It seems that you want to use LaTeX…

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the last `\vfill` is supposed to push the horizontal segment down to the bottom, without it *was (at least)* only at the very top of the vertical line

Comment: @TeXnician LaTeX, but I am interested in explicitly plain TeX ways as well. I didn't find much explaining what I wanted using LaTeX on the internet and almost nothing for TeX, and if, just answers here that are specific to one question most of the time.

Comment: Well, then I would question why you start with environments at all, because plain TeX doesn't know them. You should also rewrite the `\vspace` commands into TeX syntax (`\vskip`) etc. If you want to learn more TeX commands look at "TeX by Topic".

Comment: we can't run your example as posted, please edit the question to have a smple article class document, the environment definition _and some examples that do not work as you expect_ Just looking at the code I can't guess the intention of `\hspace{-2em}\hspace{-2.5pt}` (why not `\hspace{-4.5pt}` and why 4.5pt?) or of the `\vfill` which seems designed to move the bottom rule away from the box?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! Added. I hope I can convey my point...

Comment: Okay, that that's settled — anyone a pointer to how to rewrite my environment to enable page breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{interrupt} {%
    \par
    \addvspace{2em}%
    \noindent\hspace{2.5pt}\rule{2em}{.2pt}\hspace{\dimexpr-2.5pt-2em}%
    \vline width .8pt %
    \hspace{1.5pt}%
    \vline width .2pt %
    \hspace{2em}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5pt-4em}
    \vspace{1em}%
} {%
    \vspace{.5em}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{2em}%
    \vline width .2pt %
    \par
    \parskip0pt
    \nointerlineskip
    \noindent\hfill\rule{2em}{.2pt}\hspace*{2.5pt}%
    \par
    \addvspace{2em}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

Bla, bla blabla bla, bla.\\
Ba di da bla

\begin{interrupt} % the session and discussion is interrupted
    % and may be continued in the same context later
    How nice, a custom sample text.

    \begin{tabular}{c | c c}
        1   & 2 & 3\\\hline
        4   & 5 & 6\\
        7   & 8 & 9
    \end{tabular}
\end{interrupt}

Back to same bla\dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, it does solve my specific case and gives me some commands to look up. Can you also maybe explain where my expectation of how the boxes work was wrong? (Though I assume I have not have given enough information to make it a short answer)

Comment: you were nearly there, main thing you were missing was a `\par` after the minipage to get below it so the bottom horizontal rule is at the bottom. @PeterNerlich